# no resource found that matches the given name?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-relativelayout

This is driving me mad. My project compiled fine a moment ago. I made some minor change somewhere else, and now I'm getting this error. Here's the error message in full:

> no resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/blank_view").

Here's my XML file where the error is occurring:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_right"
        android:layout_above="@id/blank_view"
        android:src="@drawable/button" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/blank_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

How in the hell could it be failing to find a resource with the name "@id/blank_view" when that resource is *just below it in the file?*

Btw, the reason I have my layout like this is that I want the `ImageButton` to be aligned to the bottom of my relative layout, but offset up by a margin. For some reason, those two attributes (`layout_alignParentBottom` and `layout_marginBottom`) don't mix well in the same view.

I should also point out that this happened earlier as well, but I just removed the reference that was giving AndroidStudio such a problem, rather than trying to fix it. This, however, is too important to wave away like that.

Comment: Try cleaning your project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because the xml is parsed in a linear fashion and the views/objects created in a top to bottom order.  So your xml tells the view builder to put your ImageButton above an item that does not exist yet.

Just move it below the blank view and the error should go away.

Comment: or use `android:layout_above="@+id/blank_view"`

Comment: As is often the case, I learned this shortly after posting my question. But this is the right answer, and thank you for responding.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the property to your view:

```
<view 
    android:id="@+id/blank_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn" 
/>
```

And remove:

```
android:layout_above="@id/blank_view"
```